# Request fails when trying to directly upload file to amazon S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, bucket

I am trying to implement direct upload to amazonS3 on my app following these instructions :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

I have created a bucket on S3 and downloaded the credentials. Following the tutorial I have added an initializer to my rails app :

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'Ireland',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
})

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
```

I have set a before_action on my hotel_controller :

```
  before_action :set_s3_direct_post, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]

  private

   def set_s3_direct_post
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
  end
```

and I have customized my form with the appropriate JS :

```
<%= form_for(@hotel,  url: account_hotels_path(params[:account_id]), html: { class: 'directUpload', data: { 'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url, 'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :account_id, :value => params[:account_id] %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :postcode %>
    <%= f.text_field :postcode %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag "Number of rooms" %>
    <%= number_field_tag "room_number"%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag "Number of Beds in each room" %>
    <%= number_field_tag "bed_number"%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Photo" %><br>
    <%= f.file_field "photo[image_url]" %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>  
<% content_for(:after_js) do %>
  <script>
   $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
      var fileInput    = $(elem);
      var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
      var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
      var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
      var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
      fileInput.after(barContainer);
      console.log(form);
      console.log(form.data('form-data'));
      console.log(form.data('url'));
      console.log(fileInput)
      fileInput.fileupload({
        fileInput:       fileInput,
        url:             form.data('url'),
        type:            'POST',
        autoUpload:       true,
        formData:         form.data('form-data'),
        paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
        dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
        replaceFileInput: false,
        progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
      },
      start: function (e) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

        progressBar.
          css('background', 'green').
          css('display', 'block').
          css('width', '0%').
          text("Loading...");
      },
      done: function(e, data) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
        progressBar.text("Uploading done");

        // extract key and generate URL from response
        var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
        var url   = '//' + form.data('host') + '/' + key;

        // create hidden field
        var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
        form.append(input);
      },
      fail: function(e, data) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

        progressBar.
          css("background", "red").
          text("Failed");
      }
      });
    });
  </script>
<% end -%>
```

I have also changed the CORS SETTINGS of my bucket as was suggested in the tutorial.

However everytime I start uploading a file, the request fails, I get :

```
query.self-c64a74367bda6ef8b860f19e74df08927ca99d2be2ac934e9e92d5fd361e0da4.js?body=1:10244 OPTIONS https://quickbed.s3.ireland.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

and

[image]

What is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ireland` is not a valid region, in the sense that you need here... which is a regional endpoint.

You're looking for `eu-west-1`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: thanks @michael but now the request is telling 
new: ```XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://quickbed.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.``` I dont understand this message as I updated the CORS configuration of my bucket. Do you have an idea of what's wrong ?

Comment: CORS and the hostname "localhost" don't often play well together.  Access your test site using `http://lvh.me:3000/` instead of `http://localhost:3000/` and you should have better results.  It's a DNS hostname that always returns 127.0.0.1 (the IP address of localhost), useful for exactly this sort of purpose.